# Trigger open&edit file with tomcat WebDav from Java Applet

Tags: java, tomcat, webdav

Currently i have a java applet (with tomcat 6 as backend) that allow users to upload file and download file for document sharing. However, many users forget to upload the edited file back to the server.

Hence, I would like to enhance the applet to allow user to choose a *file** for edit and save directly to the web server. Without having the user to save the file to their local harddisk, and upload the *file** back to server manually.

After a few goggling, it seems WebDav is the way. I have configure tomcat with the webdav enable in the web.xml, and now i can view file and edit with a Webdav client CyberDuck.

Questions:

1. is it possible view / edit / lock the *file** without installing a webdav client?
   Reason is because i have more than 3000 desktop client using the software. Deployment of the webdav is an issue and how do i let each user to access different webdav so they do not see each other's file?
2. Is it possible to trigger local application to open a *file** inside WebDav?

*file** = means any file that are able to open from their local machine; examples: ms word, ms excel, ms powerpoint, pdf, PNG, JPG, txt and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, i manage to open it with: 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("winword http://:/xyz/.../pgl_page-bi.doc");

Problem is, every single type of files will need to have a different string inside the .exec("");   not as clean as i expected but at least it works.